# Rank of two bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose V and V' are finite spaces and A is the matrix of $\phi$ of whatever of two basis of V and V'.prove r($\phi$)=r(A).Now if we have basis $e_1 ... e_n $ the rank(A) is equal to the columns or $\phi(e_n)$.Then the rank is equal to n .Also every vector from Im $\phi$ is linear  combination of $\phi(e_1)$ ... $\phi(e_n)$ And also we know that $\phi(e_n)$ for n=1 to n are lineary indipendant vectors so this ends the proof and they have the same rank.Now in this proof I only think it will be right if we let Ker($\phi$)=0 then Im$\phi$ will have maximum rank=n,but it is not said.Am I wrong?($\phi $ is linear operator)

Comment: I think not everything is correct. E.g. there is no reason to assume that the rank of $A$ is $n$ (and in fact, this only happens to be the case if $\phi$ is an isomorphism).

Comment: @russoo If it is isomorphism yes it directly follows that if $e_i$ is basis also $\phi(e_i)$ of V, ,but here we may suppose that $e_n$ is basis but $e_1$ and $e_2$ are in Kernel$\phi$ then in Im$\phi$ we have n-2 vectors that are lineary indipendant and are combination of $\phi(x)=b=x_3\phi(e_3) ..... x_n(\phi(x_n)$).It is obvoius that n is not equal to n-2

Comment: I am not quite sure whether I can follow you. But here is hint which may guide you to the solution: Let $W$ be the image of $\phi$. Let $W'$ be the vector space generated by the columns of $A$. If you can show that $\dim W=\dim W'$, you are done. (Do you know why?)

Comment: @russoo The problem on the second part is that if we assume $e_1$ for example is in Ker$\phi$ then $\phi(x)$=$x_2\phi(e_2)....x_n\phi(e_n)$.Since $e_2....e_n $ are in Im they are indipendant and combination of $\phi(x)$ (I wrote it ).Then these  $ e_2...e_n $ are basis of V' and they are n-1.And this is where I get contradiction

Comment: @russoo if $e_1$ is in Ker.Then every vector x can be written as $x_1\phi(x_1)$ +$x_2$$\phi(x_2)$ .... $x_n.\phi(x_n)$ but $phi(x_1)=0$